# how to remove commas when retrieve from database

Tags: c#, split, parameters

```
object functionReturnValue = null;
        using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection parameter = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
            string url = "https://www.itexmo.com/php_api/api.php";
            con.Open();
            using (cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Records ", conn))
            using (datar = cmd.ExecuteReader())

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string msg = datar["Message"].ToString();
                    string sname = datar["StudentName"].ToString();
                    string bal = datar["Balance"].ToString();
                    string cy = datar["CourseYear"].ToString();
                    string pn = datar["Phonenumber"].ToString();

                    parameter.Add("1", pn.ToString()); //send
                    parameter.Add("2", msg.ToString());  //send
                    parameter.Add("2", sname.ToString());  //send 
                    parameter.Add("2", bal.ToString()); //send
                    parameter.Add("2", cy.ToString()); /send
                    parameter.Add("3", "apicode");
                    parameter.Add("passwd", "$apipass");
                    dynamic rpb = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", parameter);
                    functionReturnValue = (new System.Text.UTF8Encoding()).GetString(rpb);
                    parameter.Clear();
                }
            datar.Close();
            con.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Message has been sent!.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
```

This code send messages to the numbers from my database where i have 3 numbers, these are the message that i received while testing is like this

Hello,Juan De La Cruz,1455,Agriculture 4A

Hello,Marites Domingo,6000,Agriculture 4B

Hello,Thomas Sabado,900,Agriculture 4B

What i want to happen is to remove the excessive commas in the messages that i want to send and split it into a new line indivually.
What should i do? Thank you .

Comment: Can you please put a bit more context to your question? At which point exactly do you have to handle this messages?

A first approach could be to simple split the message string or replace the commas with  newline characters.

Comment: @DannySchneider  i want to remove the excessive commas

Comment: @kenluffy What output are you receiving? Where does it go wrong and are you receiving any errors? Or can you provide examples on what you specifically want.

Comment: Hello,Juan De La Cruz,1455,Agriculture 4A

Hello,Marites Domingo,6000,Agriculture 4B

Hello,Thomas Sabado,900,Agriculture 4B
@Rule this are the messages that i receive i want to remove the commas like this Hello Thomas Sabado 900 Agriculture 4B, these is message is composed of data from my database.

Answer (score 0):

So what you are doing is working just fine, it's the way you want to print the database retrieved items to the world which you want different?

To accomplish this I suggest you create a new CLASS called Student.cs for example, which contains all of these fields. Such as this

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Address {get;set;}
    public string Balance {get;set;}

}
```

And create a foreachloop which add a NEW Student to a list of Students.

No you can put all of your results in a list of STUDENTS. Now use a seperate function to do a 'foreach' on the students and print the student. Something like

```
string msg;
foreach(var student in students){
    msg += student.Name + " "+ student.Balance;
}
```

and print this 'msg'.

This way you can seperate your retrieve logic and your print logic. And you are in total control of all mutations and changes you want to make in the future.

Answer (score 0):

So, if msg is your comma separated string, than you can easily do something like this:

```cs
  string msg = "Hello,Juan De La Cruz,1455,Agriculture 4A";
  msg = msg.Replace(",", " ");

  Debug.Writeline(msg); //OUTPUT: Hello Juan De La Cruz 1455 Agriculture 4A
```

Comment: but the problem is that the strings in the message is from my database. "Hello" is the first, " Juan De La Cruz", "1455","Agriculture 4-A"  as follows

Comment: Sorry man, I do not not understand your problem. If you have single values from database, where do you want to remove commas?